How to click "Allow" automatically on Google Chrome pop-up using Selenium in C#
I would like to click on allow option which is coming out from a pop up of a website this I want to do on chrome browser greater than 117 version .
I am expecting to use C# code here. Using Java there are few examples present but not with c#
Popup:

enter image description here

The selenium documentation provides examples for all supported languages, including csharp. https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/alerts/

You can use selenium...
You can start building upon the example:
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Configure ChromeOptions to allow multiple file downloads
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads", 1); // Allow file download without prompt
        options.AddUserProfilePreference("download.prompt_for_download", false); // Disable the download prompt
        options.AddUserProfilePreference("download.directory_upgrade", true); // Use default download directory
        options.AddUserProfilePreference("safebrowsing.enabled", true); // Enable safe browsing

        // Set up download path if needed
        options.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", @"C:\path\to\download\directory");

        // Instantiate the Chrome driver with the specified options
        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

        // Navigate to the page where the download will occur
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://example.com/page-with-download");

        // TODO: Locate the element that triggers the download
        // For example, if the download is triggered by clicking a button with the ID 'downloadButton':
        var downloadButton = driver.FindElement(By.Id("downloadButton"));
        downloadButton.Click();

        // TODO: Add any additional actions you need to perform on the page
        // ...

        // Wait for the download to complete (optional, implement your own logic)
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000); // This is just an arbitrary wait time

        // Quit the driver, closing the browser window
        driver.Quit();
    }
}

Make sure the code reflects the logic you are after
and read through the selenium documentation

Sorry the image was just an example, basically I want to click on "allow" option from pop up which is asking me to access my camera .

It worked finally with the settings -options .AddUserProfilePreference("profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_camera", 1);
options .AddArgument("--disable-notifications");
options .AddArgument("start-maximized");
options .AddArgument("--disable-infobars");
options .AddArgument("--disable-extensions");
